# How to put a List element as Matrix? (Python)

Tags: python

I am trying to append lists into the corresponding places in the matrix.

My codes are below

```
n = 6

for i in range(0, n):
    all_paths = [[0] for _ in range(n)]*n

all_paths = np.array(all_paths).reshape((n, n))

print(all_paths)

paths = [[1, 0], [2, 0]]
all_paths[1, 5] = paths
```

The first output is

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

and I want to put the paths' list to matrix[1, 5]

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 [[1,0], [2,0]]]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Its not possible in numpy.

Comment: @balu Then what is [this](https://tio.run/##TY3BDsIgDIbvfYoewZBlavRgsidZyIKKDrOVhuGBp0fwIPbS9O/Xfpzi7OmYs1vZh4j0Xjmh2ZAYgHDAM8DDB3ToCIOhpxW9QpIXwFJmWSY2cd4KOI69xopODSWpdwTwjxF3JgSTxC9UeI@J7eCvL3uLsgt2mw1bIaiKJEAz7BX2WuF4qF23v3Vx0gX5TuUiOIrNIHP@AA)?